# What does a table type in an Oracle select clause do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have experience with SQL Server and Postgres, but am currently trying to figure out what an Oracle stored procedure does so that I can convert to SQL Server (specifically the select clause, but could use some clarification on anywhere the types are being used):

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXAMPLE_TYPE(io.column1, io.column2, io.column3)
    BULK COLLECT INTO ExampleTypeTable
    FROM Inventory_Offline io
    WHERE io.column1 = pTest
    ORDER BY EXAMPLE_TYPE(io.column1, io.column2, io.column3).column3;
```

#### Context:

```
ExampleTypeTable EXAMPLE_TYPE_TABLE;
```

```
create or replace TYPE EXAMPLE_TYPE_TABLE 
AS TABLE OF EXAMPLE_TYPE;
```

```
create or replace TYPE EXAMPLE_TYPE AS OBJECT 
(
    column1 varchar2(13),
    column2 varchar2(50),
    column3 varchar2(14),
    ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION match (io EXAMPLE_TYPE) RETURN INTEGER
);
```

I have searched around and can not find any examples of a type being used in the select clause of a query like this.

Comment: Well, going from Oracle procedures to SQL Server procedures is a hard way. Oracle's procedures are written in PL/SQL, which is a complete programming language. SQL Server only has some flow control statements and that's it.

Comment: The `EXAMPLE_TYPE` defines a class (a structure containing three columns and a member function that is needed to be able to sort the instances). `EXAMPLE_TYPE_TABLE` is the definition of an array of such records. `ExampleTypeTable` is the actual array. `BULK COLLECT INTO ExampleTypeTable` reads the query's result into that array. When this is done you can loop through this array, add or remove rows, etc. Just like in any programming language.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Ah, okay. That really helps to think of it in that context. I have never used Oracle, so I assumed it was the same as SQL Server/T-SQL, but with different syntax. Not a full programming language. Thanks for giving me some perspective on the equivalent data structures to the Oracle structures.